# How to open a pdf by pressing a button?

Tags: java, android, pdf

i am makeing an android application useful for the ones that want to take the driving licence but i don't know how to make to the following: I have the main activity. Now, by pressing the button first aid i want to apper a text or a pdf with the first aid instructions. Basically i want to do the same for mecanical and legislation. sorry for my english, it's not my first language.

Comment: You can open a pdf launching from you activity a pdf-reader-app, if you have one installed, but displaying a text is a simpler and lighter task, I think. Do you really need a pdf?

Comment: i just need to display a text with some images. I just figure it out that it's easier to put all the informations in a pdf and open it by clicking the button.

Comment: I suggest not to use a pdf, you have to assume that the user has a pdf-reader app installed to open your content. If you have content in plain text and image files just display them in your app, it's really a trivial task

Comment: i'm sure that for you it's super easy but i'm a beginner so i need to do some research cause it's the only way i can learn something. thx!!!

Comment: I'm sure you will be able to achieve this task very soon...! Look for TextView and ImageView, or, if you are more confident with html/css formatting, you can also use a WebView and load your content there and display them as you would do in a web-browser...good luck!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For openinig pdf file on click of button.put following code in listener.

```
 String FILE = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/abc.pdf";   

 File file = new File(FILE); 

 //file should contain path of pdf file/
 Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
 intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
 intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

 try {
       startActivity(intent);
     } 
     catch (ActivityNotFoundException e)
     {
            Toast.makeText(this, 
                "No Application Available to View PDF", 
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

Comment: i named my pdf abc.pdf and the path it's C:\Users\Cristina\Desktop\spatiu de lucru\VreauCarnet!\assets. At the line  Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file); what exactly i need to write?

Comment: put your pdf file in sdcard and checked it with edited answer.

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ipRke1P4rIc copy your pdf file from ur pc to sd card @Madhuri